# How to regex to match two non-necessarily consecutive parentheses between $'s

Tags: regular-expressions

I would like to write a regular expression to match two parentheses `(` between $'s  (not necessarily consecutive).

For example`$c(ad(b*$`, `$a((*b$` and `$$*(a(b(*$$`  are match but `$a($` and `$(a)$` are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dollar sign `[$]`, followed possibly by some chars that are neither a dollar sign nor a left paren `[^$(]*`, followed by a left paren `[(]`, followed (again) possibly by some chars that are neither a dollar sign nor a left paren `[^$(]*`, followed by a dollar sign `[$]`.

```
"[$][^$(]*[(][^$(]*[(].*[$]"
```

Comment: Why not `\$[^$(]*([^$(]*(.*\$`?

Comment: No reason not. I thought the version I gave might be more self-explanatory. No need to know that `(` is not special or to know how to escape special chars such as `$`. (And yes, if it were for my own code, I would write what you wrote.)